# Android device returning wrong value for last digit of sim number

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am fetching sim number using below code .

```
TelephonyManager phoneMgr = (TelephonyManager).getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
phoneMgr.getSimSerialNumber();
```

its fetching sim number too, but when I compare fetched value from the value displayed on my sim card ***it is giving last digit wrong***.

**Fetching**: 899**************7F

**Expected**: 899*************7U

Any idea why it Is happening?